# MariaDB / mYSQL Order BY PrimaryKey DESC vs DESC set by Default

Tags: mysql, mariadb, primary-key, order-by

What do you guys think about:
After each query, I put "Order BY PrimaryKey DESC"
 VS
I set "PrimaryKey Sort by DESC Default" and each query I don't need to put Order By there.

Which one will be faster and skip the sort? 
OR both of them do sort? nothing optimize ?

Comment: to guarantee the resulset to be sorted you need to use ORDER BY even if you want to sort it ascending

Answer (score 1):

Before MySQL 8.0, and MariaDB:

You *may* use `DESC` in an index declaration, but it is *ignored*.  (The `PRIMARY KEY` is an index.)

You *must* say `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause if you want the resultset sorted that way.

For multi-column indexes, all columns in `ORDER BY` should go the same way (all ASC or all DESC) in order to be able to use an `INDEX`.  (There are many cases where an index won't be useful for `ORDER BY` anyway.)

MySQL 8.0:  `DESC` is honored in `INDEXes`.